# let $A$ a nonempty subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ that is bounded above, then $ \bigcup A \in A $??

Tags: real-analysis

in this question $ \mathbb{R} $ is defined as set of Dedekind cuts on $ \mathbb{Q} $

let $ A $ a nonempty subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ that is bounded above, and $ \bigcup A:=\{x|\exists B \in A(x \in B)\} \in A $

I must proof that $ \bigcup A \in A $

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not correct: Let $B_n=\{ x\in \Bbb Q:x\lt 1-\frac 1n\}$ and $A=\{ B_n:n\in \Bbb Z^+\}$, then $\bigcup A=\{ x\in \Bbb Q:x\lt 1\} \notin A$.

*Edit:* Note that $\bigcup A=\mbox{sup}A,$ so really it suffices to take any subset of $\Bbb R$ which doesn't contain its supremum.

Comment: mmmmm ok... in my question $\bigcup A$ is an upper bound of $A$??

Comment: Yes, in fact it is the least upper bound of $A$.

Comment: okok but if $\bigcup A=sup A$ then $\bigcup A$ is a greatest element of $A$..., but if $\bigcup A$ is a greatest element of $A$ then $\bigcup A$ is an upper bound of $A$ and $\bigcup A \in A$, is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure about which definitions you use, but normally a set need not contain its supremum. And a set definitely doesn't contain all its upper bounds.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_element line 5!!

Comment: $\mbox{sup}A$ is not the *greatest element* of $A$, it is the *least upper bound*. It is true that if $A$ has a greatest element, then it is $\mbox{sup}A$, but if $\mbox{sup}A\notin A$, then $A$ has no greatest element. E.g. consider $A=[0,1)$, then $\mbox{sup}A=1\notin A$ and $A$ has no greatest element.

Comment: OKOK I was wrong to write sorry!!! the least upper bound of $A$ is the maximum of $A$ and the minimum of $T$, with $T:=\{x| x \text{ is a upper bound of }A\}$? correct?

Comment: NO! $supA$ is the minimum of $T$, but not the maximum of $A$ (only if $supA\in A$).

Comment: okok... ;) thanks soo much!

Comment: but therefore $T $ is bounded below ??